# Updating React state with Relay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, relay, graphql

With Relay, you create a React component as usual:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

And then component is wrapped in a Relay container:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(TodoApp, {
  ...
});
```

The Relay container will fetch data using GraphQL and then update the state. This is a higher order component and this state is then passed down as props to its children.

This isn't (or doesn't appear to be) compatible with a flux implementation like Redux. Redux has a single global state object and it too has higher order components that pass props down to presentational components. So I don't see how both the Redux store and Relay containers can coexist currently.

So then how should we update state that doesn't come from the database? How is this state supposed to be managed with Relay?

Answer (score 5):

While I can’t offer you an advice on using them together, **technically you can definitely have several higher order components applied one after another:**

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

TodoApp = connect(
  // ...
)(TodoApp);

TodoApp = Relay.createContainer(TodoApp, {
  // ...
});

export default TodoApp;
```

I’m not sure this makes a lot of sense, but it’s easily doable.

Comment: Relay container should be higher level than Redux container, otherwise Relay can't pass the fragments down properly.

Answer (score 0):

These things are still in discussion and the current state of Redux and Relay may not fit well together if you use a Relay container.

You can join the discussion [here](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/464)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this as follows for a chat application:

1. The chat component (`ChatComponent`) is a dumb react component that expects all data to come as props. It also requires the redux `dispatch` function as a prop so it can dispatch actions when someone wants to send a new message. This is a 'private' component and is wrapped by...
2. ChatComponentRelay - this renders `ChatComponent` but is a Relay component which is also connected to the redux store. It uses one of the lifecycle methods (*not* the constructor) to dispatch the data received via relay into the redux store. This is the component that is used by the rest of the application, and is basically just a proxy to the underlying dumb `ChatComponent`. It renders `ChatComponent` passing in all the data in its props from the redux store, and also the redux `dispatch` function as well.