# Redux connect with Relay

Tags: reactjs, redux, relayjs

How can I use redux connect with Relay.createContainer?

should I wrapper Relay.createContainer with redux or the other way?

or should I get redux state from context? what is the best approach?

if I get data from context how can I make the component rerender when redux state change?

My component needs to get data from redux and from relay

Comment: Why are you trying to use Redux and Relay? Relay was facebooks data driven framework to essentially replace redux

Comment: I store from local data using redux, and I use Relay to do all the data fetching, I want to render a component that uses the local data (redux) and the server data (Relay)

Comment: solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34135053/2628278

Comment: Yeah but unless you are stuck doing this, why use 2 libraries instead of just 1? Redux can very easily do all your async...

Comment: Until Relay provides a concrete way / example to store non-fetched-data state without using React `this.state` combining Redux with Relay is the best solution, at least that I've been able to come up with. OP, treat your components as if React and Redux were the same library, then wrap those components with Relay containers.

Comment: concrete example: https://github.com/NCI-GDC/portal-ui-legacy/blob/feat/relay%2Bcomponents%2Bfrontend-devtools/src/js/node_modules/containers/CartPage.js#L154

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, Relay + Redux are a great fit together--there is app level state that has nothing to do with server state, data, or caching... stuff like, "is a global modal active?". It took quite a bit of soul searching and experimenting to come to this conclusion.

What I believe works the best is to treat React + Redux as if it were the default way to build your application, then wrap Relay on top of that.

```
Relay.createContainer(
  connect(mapStateToProps)(BaseComponent), 
  {
    initialVariables: { ... },
    fragments: { ... },
  }
)
```